# Angular ngbPopover, how to open a popover from a child compopent

Tags: angular, popover, ng-bootstrap

In angular with ng-Bootstrap I have a popover and a child component (app-adviser):

```
<!-- some.component.html -->
<app-adviser [text]="advisorText"></app-adviser>
<div 
    ...
    triggers="manual" 
    #p="ngbPopover" 
> </div>
```

The button to trigger the popover is in the child component:

```
<!-- adviser.component.html -->
<button type="button" (click)="p.open()">
        Open popover
</button>
```

But the popover have to be in the parent component, usually I would call click function click="p.open()", but how to do it(communicate) from a child component to a parent?

Comment: Use an `EventEmitter` from the child to trigger the `popover`.

Comment: Thank you, I got it

Answer (score -1):

If the popover's content and the button are both in the child component, you have to move all the popover's logic from the parent to the child component. In the stackblitz bellow you can see an example.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/popover-in-child-component?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild-component.html

Comment: thank you for your answer, but the popover must stay in the parent component and the button in child component.

Comment: In that case you have to use an event emitter. see the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/open-popover-in-parent-from-child?file=src/app/parent/parent-component.html